# Unnable to connect/deploy app to/on device

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, deployment

I am unnable to deploy apps/connnec to to my device on my notebook.

Problem description:

- VS 2012 update 3, project is wp7, freshly installed
- Windows 8.1 Enterprise (fully updated), freshly installed
- HTC titan 7.8
- sometimes I can deploy but like in 1:100
- turning off wifi does not have any effect
- mostly I get an error in VS: "This operation returned because the timeout period expired."
- I can connect with wpconnect.exe(it takes a while) but I am still unnable to deploy in VS (timeout error)
- I do not have any problems in device manager
- Device manager shows Portable devices/HTC TITAN - LB
- I can deploy on my other PC (also running W8.1 and with the same phone and cable and VS 2012 update 3), but not on my notebook
- zune (newest one) mostly does not recognize phone at all, just showing "device"
  , sometimes it detects my phone (sync relation guest)
- with zune running and phone recognized the VS 2012 shows: "Failed to connect to the device. Ensure that the device is completely booted and is connected to the PC" (phone is fysically connected and unlocked in homescreen)
- if zune is running and phone is not recognized (showing "device" instead of "phone") VS shows timeout error

Any suggestions? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Point number six. Once I was getting that sort of error and it was due to VS. I uninstalled it and I made a fresh install, then everything worked fine.

Comment: I should have stated this, but it is in fact a fresh install. It did it before so I decided to reinstall OS, VS...